# grouping elements and adding their element values in xslt

Tags: xslt

**source document:**
the below is the xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Library>
<Book code="123">
    <BookName>XML</BookName>
    <Category>Programming</Category>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    <Price>100</Price>
</Book>
<Book code="345">
    <BookName>Photoshop</BookName>
    <Category>Design</Category>
    <Quantity>50</Quantity>
    <Price>200</Price>
</Book>
<Book code="123">
    <BookName>XML</BookName>
    <Category>Programming</Category>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <Price>100</Price>
</Book>
<Book code="345">
    <BookName>Photoshop</BookName>
    <Category>Design</Category>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    <Price>200</Price>
</Book>
  <Book code="456">
    <BookName>Illustrator</BookName>
    <Category>Design</Category>
    <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    <Price>300</Price>
</Book>    
</Library>
```

**xslt stylesheet:**
this is the present stylesheet. I have tried to use xslt 2. However, I am not getting how to get the desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
 <h1>Books Information</h1>
 <table border="1">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="Library/Book" group-by="Category">
 <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
 <tr>
<td colspan="4">Category:
  <b>
     <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
   </b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Book Code</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>    
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="@code"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Book">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**current output**

```
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Books Information</h1>
  <table border="1">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Category:
              <b>Design</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Book Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>345</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>345</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Category:
              <b>Programming</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Book Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**expected output**

```
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>Books Information</h1>
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Category:
              <b>Design</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Book Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>345</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>1200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Subtotal: 1500</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Category:
              <b>Programming</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Book Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>1500</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">subtotal: 1500</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Grand TOtal: 3000</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you wanted to compute a subtotal, of which values do you want to compute the subtotal, of the Price of all items in a group, or of the product of Quantity and Price of all items in a group?

Comment: I want to add the quantity of all the books having the same code number and multiply it with thier per unit price and display the total price on the Price column i.e. category wise.  [quantity * price = total price] [subtotal will be based on the category] . Thanks Martin

Comment: Yes I want to compute Product of Quantity and Price of all items in a group

Comment: @user3243634 I have rolled back your question to its original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing two lots of grouping here. First by "Category" and within each category you then group by "Code".

You first grouping looks fine, but for the second grouping, you need to replace these lines...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="@code"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

With these lines, as this will then group the books within the current category by their code

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@code">
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In terms of getting the totals for each group, you can use this expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/(Quantity * Price))" />
```

This will work for both groups, so can be used to get the amount for the "code" and the sub-total for the "category". For the overall total, it would just be this

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(Library/Book/(Quantity * Price))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
 <h1>Books Information</h1>
 <table border="1">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="Library/Book" group-by="Category">
 <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
 <tr>
<td colspan="4">Category:
  <b>
     <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
   </b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Book Code</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>    
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@code">
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:for-each-group>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">subtotal: <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/(Quantity * Price))" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Total: <xsl:value-of select="sum(Library/Book/(Quantity * Price))" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Book">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@code"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/(Quantity * Price))" /></td>
</tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. Great HELP

Comment: Hello Tim, can you please check this questions. I dont know how to use for-each-group here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297376/xml-to-pdf-by-xsl-fo